# How can I tell my screen's resolution in Puppy Linux?

Tags: integrated-graphics

How can I tell my screen's resolution in Puppy Linux?

I’m a Windows user but would like to lean the minimum on Linux. I’m using Puppy Linux and I love it enough to switch to Linux for good.

Comment: Which version of Puppy are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to open a terminal emulator and view output of `xrandr` command. This will give you a list of connected monitors and modes (resolution and refresh frequency) available for them. Mode marked with `*` is the current one.

Edit: 
Relevant section of Puppy linux wiki: http://puppylinux.org/wikka/xRandr